# How to get table's size with Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

If `Me.Subform_name.Height` and `Me.Subform_name.Width` are the strings to get the size of the **Subform** "*Subform_name*", what are the strings to get the size of the **Table** "*Table_name*"?

EDIT:
With "**Table**" I mean a table of the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option, if you mean the table content.

If it is the measures of the table when opened and displayed (which is done internally using a form not member of the Forms collection), you can use something like:

```
With Screen.ActiveForm
    Debug.Print .Height, .Width
End With
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but with "Table" I mean a table of the database. I was no clear.

Comment: Yes, that what the answer covers.